# How to pass information from one reducer to another in MapReduce

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I have two mappers and two reducers (1 and 2). My driver class runs two jobs that take in two different input files and output two different output files (again, 1 and 2). So job1 is associated with inputfile1, outputfile1, map1 and reduce1; similarly for job2.

Reduce1 outputs data of the form (id, number) using context.write. My goal is to access these key value pairs in Reduce2, but I cannot figure out how. I have tried doing a conf.setInt in reduce1, but the values are not being passed into reduce2, because I don't get them when I do a conf.getInt.

Comment: Why not use Spark over MapReduce?

Comment: @cricket_007 can't. I have to use MapReduce

Comment: Alright, I can say from experience that no one I've worked with in the last 5 years actually has written Mapreduce, but anyway, The Configuration class that you're trying to use should persist across the entire job lifecycle. Or you just make the output path of job1 as the input path of job2 (which is what Hive,Pig,Spark,etc would do).... Can you share your code, please?

Comment: can not you use apache oozie workflow??  Why can you just not use a double MapReduce operation to join the two data sources?

Answer (score 0):

Coming back to this, in my experience, you write output to one path, then run another job with that path as input...

In theory, you can create two Jobs in one program if you add more code after the `waitForCompletion` method on the first Job